# Skip dependency checking for .NET Core console app

Tags: .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 console app that is compiled to exe using the `<RuntimeIdentifier>` setting in the config file. 
During build, it copies all dependencies (236 files) to the output and with these dependencies it seems to be running fine. There is a `.deps.json` file listing all these.

The tool is a dev tool and it is executed in machines where Visual Studio and .NET Core 2.1 is anyway installed, so I tried to delete all .NET framework dependencies from the output folder (reduced to 10 files).

As a result it runs fine **on my machine**, but I have another machine where it complains about the missing depenencies. These dependencies are in the .nuget folder in both machines (with the same versions).

I get errors like

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (myconsoleapp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions', version: '2.0.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll'
```

I would like to understand better what causes the difference between the two machines. It seems that on one the dependencies are checked even before running a single line of the code in the other it does not work like that.

Is there a preliminary dependency check that can be switched off somehow?

Why is it like this? Is there a good way to diagnose this?

Comment: If it is truly a tool for developers, make it a global tool, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools

Comment: @LexLi yes, that would make sense. I will think on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after a couple of hours of research, I think I understand the loading concept better. Nate McMaster has written a great [blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/) that also contains some further references at the end. These I can recommend to anyone who wants to have a better understanding.

In my concrete case the difference was caused by the `.runtimeconfig.dev.json` that I have copied along with my other files, without noticing that it is actually containing the packages folder of my own user `C:\Users\gaspar\.nuget\packages`. On the other machine the user name was different so .NET Core could not load the assemblies.